# Javascript SSE sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I have a flask app with a SSE endpoint which looks like

```
@app.route('/chatlisten', methods=['GET'])
def listen():
    from_id, to_id = int(request.args['from_id']), int(request.args['to_id'])
        
    def stream():
        message = message_queue.listen(from_id, to_id)
        while True:
            msg = message.get()
            yield f"data:{msg}\n\n"

    return Response(stream(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

It always works on localhost, but when deployed it's extremely hit or miss. If I add a print statement after `msg = message.get()` it prints the message. Things should be working, I read somewhere this could be a network issue. What can I do to get SSE working reliably?

The app is served with gunicorn using gevent workers.

The url gives me 504 (Gateway Timeout) after a certain amount of time. Does SSE go through a different port? why is it getting timed out?

Comment: Where do you deploy it to? You should confirm that platform supports SSE (or sockets or streaming) e.g. Google App Engine Standard doesn't

Comment: I left a ticket, it seems like even if I don't go through a load balancer and access the server directly I have this problem (although the connection doesn't time out). Seems to be a platform compatibility problem then?

Comment: After contacting my provider it seems like things are working, but their response did not relate the issue in anyway. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Who is your provider?